# How to keep a button at the bottom center of a dynamically changing div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So i have a container with a some text and a button after the text. This widget is repeated several times on my screen. Each container is having its height set based on the height of its contents and its a bootstrap column so its width changes as well. My problem is I want the button to always stick to the bottom of its widget, but if I set the `position: absolute; bottom:0; right:25%;` it is only centered as long as the widgets width doesn't change. Which it does. Any suggestions?

Comment: flex will make this easy ... no code = no chocolate.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Would you be able to post the code snippet?

Comment: Please show us a code and a screen shot!

Comment: don't use the `right:25%` .... use other method to center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your "flex"able friend in action. I am using some arbitrarily sized divs for illustration purposes:

```css
div {
  background: pink;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px
}

#flexDiv1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
}

#flexDiv2 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 70px;
}

#flexDiv3 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="flexDiv1">
  <a href="#">link</a>
</div>

<div id="flexDiv2">
  <a href="#">link</a>
</div>

<div id="flexDiv3">
  <a href="#">link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Check if this is what you need:**

```
<div class="holder">
  <div class='widget-footer'>
    <button class="btn-inner">
      foo
    </button>
  </div>
</div>



html, body{
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.holder{
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  /*height: 250px;*/
  background: #dedede;
  position:relative;
}
.widget-footer{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
}
.btn-inner{
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qw54w9j9/2/

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

#### CSS

```
#dinamic {
  position:relative;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ddd;
}
.center-bottom {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  text-align:center
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="dinamic">
  <div class="center-bottom">
    <button>Click-me!</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8pyn4Le4/